# Check if a date is greater than specified date

Tags: javascript

How can I check that a date is greater than or less than the specified date using javascript by passing the month and year only in `MMM-YYYY` Format.

For example :

Let the user selects **JUL** from month dropdown and **2016** from years dropdown ,

Now How can I check that the selected values are **greater than / less than** JUN 2016 .

I've taken the input in Session variables as session("month") , session("yrs").

I've tried the following but nothing happens :

```
var d1 = new Date('JUN-2016')
var d2 = new Date(<% =session("month")+"-"+session("yrs") %>) )
if(d2.getTime() > d2.getTime())
{
alert('Greater than jun 2016');
}
else
{
alert('Less than jun 2016');
}
```

I've gone through this link [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) but didn't find the solution for my condition.

As this application is developed on VB so i don't have much knowledge about that.

How can I resolve this .

Please suggest

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you tried and allow for a fatser response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
var x = new Date('JUN-2016');
var y = new Date('MAY-2016');
console.log(+x < +y);
console.log(+x > +y);
console.log(+x === +y);
```

Comment: I've tried this : var d1 = new Date('JUN-2016');
var d2 = new Date(<% =session("month")+'-'+session("yrs") %>) );
if(d2.getTime() > d2.getTime())
{
alert('greater than jun 2016');
} but there is a sytax error where I am concatenating the month and year , can u please help me

Comment: Why are you comparing same date -  if(d2.getTime() > d2.getTime())

Comment: Thanks Rohan I modified your code , it worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do a simple compare of dates. Please read more about "Date" here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Maybe this code might help:

```
var day = 1; // Since you don't care about the day just use the first day
var month = session("month"); // Use the number of the month instead of the name
var year = session("yrs");
var dateJune = Date.parse("2016-07-01"); // June
var dateInput = Date.parse(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
// Compare dates
if (dateJune > dateInput) {
    // The input is before june
} else if (dateJune < dateInput) {
    // The input is after june
} else {
    // It is june
}
```

You need a valid date format to be able to parse the date. Instead of getting "JUN" from your select box it would be better to get the number of the month instead. A select box should look like this:

```
<select>
<option value="01">Jan</option>
<option value="02">Feb</option>
...
</select>
```

If this is not an option you can use a function that calculates the number for you if you know then string values that your month variable might have:

```
function (nameOfMonth) {
   switch (nameOfMonth) {
     case 'Jan':
        return "01";
     case 'Feb':
        return "02";
     ....
   }
}
```

Comment: How the input the date in Mon-yyyy format . i've edited my question and added the code , please help me :(

Comment: @AlinaAnjum I have edited my answer. What you need is a valid date format to be able to parse, otherwise it won't work. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First convert it to date object

```
  // convert to a parseable date string:
   var dateStrA = "28/12/2013 16:20:22".replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/,        "$2/$1/$3");
    var dateStrB = "28/12/2013 16:20:11".replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/,        "$2/$1/$3");

     // now you can compare them using:
      new Date(dateStrA) > new Date(dateStrB);
```

Comment: How the input the date in Mon-yyyy format . i've edited my question and added the code , please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var date1 = Math.ceil(Math.abs(first date) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
var date2 = Math.ceil(Math.abs(second date) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
if(date1  > date2 )
   alert("date1");
else
   alert("date2");
```

Comment: How the input the date in Mon-yyyy format . i've edited my question and added the code , please help me :(

Comment: try this                  function getFormattedDate(input) {                                     
    var pattern = /(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;                                                             
    var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2){
        var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        return (p2<10?"0"+p2:p2) + " " + months[(p1-1)];
    });

    alert(result);
}

getFormattedDate("1/2013");